# Convexity of set of mixture distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convex-optimization, machine-learning, non-convex-optimization

A set of mixture distributions $Q$ is defined as,

$Q = \{f | f(.) = \sum_{i=1}^{k} q_{i} f_{i}(.) \}$,

where each $f_{i}$ is a probability density and $\sum_{i=1}^{k} q_{i}=1$ and $q_{i}>0$.

Is set of all mixture distributions, $Q$ a convex set?

To check if it is convex or not, I took two members $f_{1}$ and $f_{2}$ and tried to check if $\lambda f_{1} + (1-\lambda)f_{2} \in Q$ where $\lambda \in [0,1] $.

But not sure, how to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

Well let $g,h \in Q$ and $g = \sum_{i=1}^kq_i f_i$ and $h = \sum_{i=1}^kp_i f_i$ the representations given by definition of $Q$. Then
\begin{align*}
\lambda g+(1-\lambda)h &= \lambda \sum_{i=1}^kq_i f_i+(1-\lambda)\sum_{i=1}^kp_i f_i\\ 
&= \sum_{i=1}^k(\lambda q_i+(1-\lambda)p_i)f_i\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^kr_if_i
\end{align*}
where I defined $r_i:= \lambda q_i+(1-\lambda)p_i$. So it remains to check, that $\sum_{i=1}^kr_i = 1$ and $r_i>0$. The latter is trivial, for the former we calculate
$$\sum_{i=1}^kr_i = \lambda \sum_{i=1}^kq_i+(1-\lambda)\sum_{i=1}^kp_i = \lambda +(1-\lambda) = 1$$
Hope that helps.

Comment: So can I say that convexity holds true only when each member of Q mixture is formed of some fixed k probability densities. Am I right here?